# Method add not found in class java.util.GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, tomcat

Al ejecutar un java en un webserver (Tomcat 8.5.15), Java (jdk1.8.0_221) obtengo el siguiente error

> Target exception: Error in method invocation: Method add( int, null ) not found in class'java.util.GregorianCalendar' : at Line: 169 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``package odonto.calendario;  import java.sql.CallableStatement; import java.sql.R . . . '' : turnoFin .add ( Calendar .MINUTE , nDuracion )

Codigo de la clase

```
package odonto.calendario;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import prg.glz.FrameworkException;
import prg.util.cnv.ConvertException;
import prg.util.cnv.ConvertList;
import prg.util.cnv.ConvertNumber;
import prg.util.cnv.ConvertDate;
import prg.util.db.hlp.ConexionHelper;

public class Calendario {
    private HttpServletRequest request = null;
    private ConexionHelper     cnxHlp  = null;

    private SimpleDateFormat   fmtDateIso = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    private SimpleDateFormat   fmtDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
    private SimpleDateFormat   fmtUTC     = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" );

    public Calendario(HttpServletRequest req, ConexionHelper cnxHlp) {
        this.request = req;
        this.cnxHlp = cnxHlp;
    }

    public Map getDisponibleMensual() throws SQLException, ConvertException, FrameworkException, ParseException {
        Integer pProfesional;
        try {
            pProfesional = ConvertNumber.toInteger( this.request.getParameter( "calendar" ) );
            if (pProfesional == null)
                throw new FrameworkException( "Falta parámetro: calendar" );

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new FrameworkException( "Parámetro calendar no es un número válido" );
        }

        Calendar vRangoIni;
        try {
            // fmtUTC.parse( this.request.getParameter( "startDate" ).substring( 0, 10 ) )
            vRangoIni =  ConvertDate.toCalendar(this.request.getParameter( "startDate" ).substring( 0, 10 ));

            if (vRangoIni == null) 
                throw new FrameworkException( "Falta parámetro: startDate" );

        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            throw new FrameworkException( "Parámetro startDate no es una fecha válida" );
        }

        Calendar vRangoFin;
        try {
            vRangoFin = ConvertDate.toCalendar( this.request.getParameter( "endDate" ).substring( 0, 10 ) );

            if (vRangoFin == null) 
                throw new FrameworkException( "Falta parámetro: endDate" );

        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            throw new FrameworkException( "Parámetro startDate no es una fecha válida" );
        }

        Integer nDuracion;
        try {
            nDuracion = ConvertNumber.toInteger( this.request.getParameter( "prm_duracion" ) );

        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            throw new FrameworkException( "Parámetro prm_duracion no es una número válida" );
        }

        List lisTurnosTomados = new ArrayList();
        List lisTurnosDiponibles = new ArrayList();

        Map mapHorarios = getHorarios(pProfesional);

        Calendar fecha = (Calendar) vRangoIni.clone();
        fecha.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        fecha.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        fecha.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        while (fecha.before(vRangoFin)) {
            Integer nDiaSemana = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            Boolean bExiste = null;
            String cInicio = null;
            String cFin = null;

            switch (nDiaSemana) {
                case 1:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BLUNES").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TLUNES_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TLUNES_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BMARTES").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TMARTES_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TMARTES_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BMIERCOLES").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TMIERCOLES_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TMIERCOLES_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BJUEVES").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TJUEVES_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TJUEVES_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BVIERNES").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TVIERNES_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TVIERNES_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BSABADO").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TSABADO_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TSABADO_FIN");
                    }
                    break;

                case 7:
                    bExiste = mapHorarios.get("BDOMINGO").toString().equals("1");
                    if (bExiste) {
                        cInicio = (String) mapHorarios.get("TDOMINGO_INICIO");
                        cFin = (String) mapHorarios.get("TDOMINGO_FIN");
                    }
                    break;
            }

            if (bExiste) {
                Calendar turnoIni = (Calendar) fecha.clone();
                Calendar turnoFin = (Calendar) fecha.clone();
                Calendar fechaFin = (Calendar) fecha.clone();
                Calendar turnoTomadoIni = Calendar.getInstance();
//              Calendar turnoTomadoFin = Calendar.getInstance();

                Integer nHoraIni = ConvertNumber.toInteger( cInicio.subSequence(0, 2) );
                Integer nHoraFin = ConvertNumber.toInteger( cFin.subSequence(0, 2) );

                turnoIni.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, nHoraIni);
                turnoFin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, nHoraIni);
                turnoFin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, nDuracion);

                fechaFin.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, nHoraFin);

                lisTurnosTomados = getTurnosTomados(pProfesional, turnoIni, turnoFin);

                Integer idxTurno = 0;
                Map turnoTomado = new HashMap();

                if (lisTurnosTomados.size() > idxTurno) {
                    turnoTomado = (Map) lisTurnosTomados.get(idxTurno);
                    turnoTomadoIni.setTime(fmtDateTime.parse((String) turnoTomado.get("FECHA_INICIO")));
//                  turnoTomadoFin.setTime(fmtDateTime.parse((String) turnoTomado.get("FECHA_FIN")));

                } else {
                    turnoTomadoIni = (Calendar) fecha.clone();
                    turnoTomadoIni.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                    turnoTomadoIni.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
                }

                while (turnoFin.before(fechaFin)) {
                    if (turnoFin.before(turnoTomadoIni)) {
                        // Turno disponible     
                        turnoIni.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                        turnoIni.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                        turnoFin = (Calendar) turnoIni.clone();
                        turnoFin.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

                        Map turno = new HashMap();
                        turno.put("calendarId", pProfesional);
                        turno.put("allDay", true);
                        turno.put("title", "Disponible");
                        turno.put("startDate", fmtUTC.format(turnoIni.getTime()));
                        turno.put("endDate", fmtUTC.format(turnoFin.getTime()));

                        lisTurnosDiponibles.add(turno);
                        break;

                    } else {
                        // Existe un turno ya tomado
                        if (lisTurnosTomados.size() > idxTurno++) {
                            turnoTomado = (Map) lisTurnosTomados.get(idxTurno);
                            turnoTomadoIni.setTime(fmtDateTime.parse((String) turnoTomado.get("FECHA_INICIO")));
//                          turnoTomadoFin.setTime(fmtDateTime.parse((String) turnoTomado.get("FECHA_FIN")));

                        } else {
                            turnoTomadoIni = fecha.getInstance();
                            turnoTomadoIni.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
                            turnoTomadoIni.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
                        }
                    }

                    turnoIni.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                    turnoFin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
                }
            }

            fecha.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        Map mResp = new HashMap();
        mResp.put( "success", true );
        mResp.put( "count", lisTurnosDiponibles.size() );
        mResp.put( "turnos", lisTurnosDiponibles );

        return mResp;
    }
```

El error se produce en la siguiente linea

```
turnoFin.add(Calendar.MINUTE, nDuracion);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo add que menciona se le debe pasar dos variables int, la primera indica el campo del calendario, el segundo (que falta porque muestra null) indica el augmento de dicho campo.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, efectivamente el parametro nDuracion era nulo.